# Как правильно проверить тип данных? Где ошибка в коде?

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию, которая проверяет тип данных переданного аргумента и:
    если это число, возвращает текущую дату
    если нет - возвращает строку "Неверный тип данных". Где ошибка в коде? Только начинаю изучать JS, поэтому могу ошибиться в нескольких местах.

```js
var a = prompt ("Введите число")
var date = new Date;
        
function showSymbol(symbol) {
  if (typeof symbol === 'number')
      console.log(date);
  else console.log("error");
}

showSymbol(a);
```

Comment: дак вам `typeof symbol` то что возвращает? `String` небось, а когда приведете к числу то `Number` будет с большой буквы, а не с маленькой? или как?

Comment: https://medium.com/devschacht/javascript-typeof-43591ab15bef

Comment: @teran мне нужно, чтоб после введения символа шла проверка и если это число, то выдавало бы дату, если не число, то строку "Error" Мой код выдает и в том и в том случае "Error" при вызове функции

Comment: оформил ваш код сниппетом, добавил вызов самой функции

Comment: а я вам вроде написал, почему error. во первых потому что `prompt` возвращает строку. А во вторых, если бы даже это было число, то вы бы сравнивали `Number == number`, и эти строки не равны. То что вы ввели руками `123` не значит, что переменная будет иметь числовой типа, будет возвращена строка.

Comment: проводите опыты на `showSymbol(1); showSymbol('qwe')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из `prompt()`, `input()` и прочих текстовых полей без явного объявление того, что текст будет числом - мы будем получать всегда тип `String`.

По этому нужно привести значение к типу `Number` или же использовать функцию 
`isNaN`, подробнее на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

> **isNaN("37")**      => false: "37" преобразуется в число 37 которое не NaN
>   **isNaN("blabla")**   => true: "blabla" преобразованно в число.

Исходя из этого мы проверяем является ли результат работы `isNaN` противоположным  и тогда уже выполняем код:

```js
var a = prompt("Введите число")
var date = new Date().toLocaleString();

if (!isNaN(a)) {
  console.log(date);
} else {
  console.log('error')
}
```

Можно и не приводить к противоположному значению результат `isNaN` - тогда это будет выглядеть вот так:

```js
var a = prompt("Введите число")
var date = new Date().toLocaleString();

if (isNaN(a)) {
  console.log('error')
} else {
  console.log(date);
}
```

Comment: @viks всегда пожалуйста, если ответ был полезен - можете это показать нажав на стрелочку вверх, и явно необходимо выбрать ответ который вам помог решить вашу задачу. Успехов в познании Javascript! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Для проверки лучше использовать комбинацию `typeof` и [`!isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Он разве не использует `typeof`?

Comment: Я говорю, что лучше добавить к typeof еще и !isNaN(), поскольку например(так делать не стоит, но все же) 
let num1 = Number('t12');
typeof(num1); вернет "number"

Answer (score 2):

так ?

```js
 let number = prompt('Введите число', '');

function time(a){

  if( +number ){
    console.log( new Date )
  } else{
    console.log( 'Неверный тип данных' )
  }

}

time( number );
```